# Custom ROM installation without PC

Tags: rom-flashing, micromax

I have downloaded many ROMs for my Android device (Micromax A120) but can't flash them. Can someone tell me how to flash those ROMs without any PC.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend flashing ROM's without PC (Or other device).

Because think about it, if you want to flash it using a program or something else, then you are changing the system while the system is running, which is definitely not good (Some files might corrupt).

But if you are using the SD card method, then that might be good enough..
But still, PC flashes ROM without the actual android to work anything.

For flashing with PC, I would recommend this [Link: XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2777619). Tho you might find an easier way with some research, or someone else might know an easier way for your device.

If you are really determined, you can use those links to get the general sense of it; (Btw, most of the methods to flash it self requires Root)

**Warning: You will void your warranty if you Root or Flash custom ROM.**

[AndroidPit: Samsung devices to flash custom ROM w/o PC](https://www.androidpit.com/how-to-flash-roms-on-samsung-devices-without-a-pc)

[TechnoWorm: Flash custom ROM w/o PC](http://technoworm.com/how-to-flash-custom-recovery-without-pc/)

[AndroidForums: Flash ROM w/o PC](http://androidforums.com/threads/flashing-roms-without-a-pc.521699/)

[Skyneel: Root Micromax A120](https://www.skyneel.com/2014/05/how-to-root-micromax-a120-canvas-2-color-without-pc.html)